# Xamarin, C#, Как сохранить информацию для вторичного использования приложения?

Tags: android, c#, xamarin-studio

Есть приложение, в ней я создаю какой-то объект, заполняю в нем поля, допустим "name" и "phone". Как мне сохранить этот объект, чтобы после перезагрузки приложения мои объекты сохранились?

Comment: xml, бд, файл !?

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/application-class/#Properties_Dictionary

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться *shared preferences*:

```
var sharedPreferences = Android.Preferences.PreferenceManager(Android.App.Application.Context);
var defaultPhone = "+79991112233";
var phone = sharedPreferences.GetString("phone", defaultPhone);

// меняем значение
usin (var editor = sharedPreferences.Edit())
{
    var newPhone = "+79995556677";
    editor.PutString("phone", newPhone);
    editor.Apply();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему, правильный путь — [application properties](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/application-class/#Properties_Dictionary).

В начале работы пишете

```
var props = Application.Current.Properties;
var name = props.ContainsKey("name") ?
    (string)props["name"] : <тут имя по умолчанию>;
var phone = props.ContainsKey("phone") ?
    (string)props["phone"] : <тут телефон по умолчанию, например, null>;
```

Когда имя/телефон поменяется, то

```
Application.Current.Properties["name"] = <новое имя>;
Application.Current.Properties["phone"] = <новый телефон>;
await Application.Current.SavePropertiesAsync();
```

Comment: Что если я не использую Xamarin.Forms, а просто Xamarin встроенный в студио, говорит что Application не содержит Current @VladD

Comment: @ЕвгенийЕфименко: Эээ... Окей, а какой _точный_ тип у вашего `Application`? Вместе с неймспейсами?

Comment: В студио при создании пректа выбираю Андройд->Blank App(Android), а какие namespace тебе показать? using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using System.IO;
using Android.Graphics;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Android.Content.Res;

namespace CreateAcount@VladD

Comment: @ЕвгенийЕфименко: А что говорит `typeof(Program).FullName`?

Comment: вывело Android.Renderscripts.Program после того как пришлось подключить библ Android.Renderscripts @VladD

Comment: @ЕвгенийЕфименко: Странное что-то. Может быть, имело смысл не выбирать Blank App?

Comment: Да многие так делают, стандартные обучающие уроке, все повторяю за ними ,а вот по сохранению нет ничего, по крайне мере не нашел, я нахожу только на джава, а на шарпе вообще нет ничего @VladD

Comment: Ох, видеоуроки :-\ Вы бы лучше книгу почитали, в книгах всё рассказывается так, чтобы вопросы отпали сами собой.

Comment: Кстати я читал туториал по xamarin , Для андройда ничего про файловую систему не сказано толкового, а вот про IOS дай боженька@VladD

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45065/discussion-between---and-vladd).

Answer (score 0):

Для таких целей существует AccountStore.

1. Берем из Nutget Xamarin.Auth
2. Пример

   `//Сохраняем
       Account account = new Account
       {
       Username = userName
       };
       account.Properties.Add ("Phone", "+11111111111");
       AccountStore.Create ().Save (account, App.AppName);
       //вытаскиваем данные
       AccountStore.Create().FindAccountsForService(App.AppName);`

Пример на Xamarin forms. В xamarin Native аналогично все. https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/general/store-credentials/